# Download static file displayed in the list Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make static files download-able from the template of my Django app.

```
def list(request):
    folder = '/home/galander/Desktop/Projekty/django-pdf-generator/django-pdf/generator/static/pdfs'

    file_list = os.listdir(folder)
    return render_to_response('list.html', {'file_list': file_list})


def download_file(request):
    pdf_folder = '/home/galander/Desktop/Projekty/django-pdf-generator/django-pdf/generator/static/pdfs'
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_folder, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="nowy.pdf"'
    return response
```

list.html

```
{% for file in file_list %}
    <a href="/home/galander/Desktop/Projekty/django-pdf-generator/django-pdf/generator/static/pdfs/{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

My current output is rather obvious at the moment - Django is looking for matching url pattern and it fails. My filename="nowy.odf" in download_file(request): is hard-coded atm just for testing purposes.

2 Solutions I am thinking of:

1) Create appropriate regex for url pattern in url.py to satisfy redirection to my download_file view which i fail to accomplish
2) I should change the display method for my static/pdf folder somehow

*update*

I have previously add STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT as also run collectstatic ( my app is generating pdfs and saving them into static folder, that was required to do so). I've also added URL pattern part (with serve, not static_view.serve becuase docs say so).

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += [
    url(
        r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,  # NOQA
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        'show_indexes': True}
    ),
] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()  # NOQA
```

My Project looks like that:
[image]

Unfortunately I don't understand the path with static upfront

```
    <a href="{% static 'django-pdf/generator/static/pdfs/nowy.pdf' %}">{{ file }}</a>
```

To be more accurate, how the    static   works here and what does that mean. Current output just shows that the file wasn't found. App doesn't work in debug mode atm.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of django's static files app.

Usually in your `settings.py` you'll define static paths something like;

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-collection')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then you run `manage.py collectstatic` which gathers all of your static files into your `STATIC_ROOT` directory which you have your project serve from your `STATIC_URL`.

In debug mode you can add the following to your `urls.py`;

```
urlpatterns = []

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(
            r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', static_views.serve,  # NOQA
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'show_indexes': True}
        ),
    ] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()  # NOQA
```

So, looking at what you've posted, your project is probably `Projekty` and one of your apps is `django-pdf-generator`. If you have a static directory in your apps, django will collect the static files in to your `STATIC_ROOT` during `collectstatic`. So maybe have a path like `Projekty/django-pdf-generator/static/django-pdf/generator/pdfs`

Based on that, in a template you might do;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>My website</title>

    <!-- ALL OF THE STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
</head>

<body>

    <p>Click <a href="{% static 'pdfs/nowy.pdf' %}">here</a> to download my PDF</p>


</body>
```

Hopefully you can see in the template there how the path matches up to the static path in your app?

Comment: When I hard-coded my url pattern to `url(r'^home/galander/Desktop/Projekty/django-pdf-generator/django-pdf/generator/static/pdfs/nowy.pdf/', views.download_file, name='download_file')` it's loading download_view.view and works perfectly however obviously it shouldn't be hard-coded. It seems that creating regex to url pattern matching the path of the file would work here. However, I am lacking with the idea how to make it dynamic

Comment: Ok, with your static settings like that I think django will complain that your static root & static URL are the same. Also, `{% static %}` is just django's static application's template tag for the inclusion of static files in templates. Based on your screenshot you could include the PDF files in your template like; `{% static 'pdfs/nowy.pdf' %}`. You said you're generating PDFs though. If you're creating content you shouldn't be storing it in static. Have a look for some tutorials or something; https://djangobook.com/generating-pdfs/

Comment: This still doesn't work. I am looking for proper regex to match my requirements atm. About saving files in static folder - I have a requirement to avoid keeping files in db. The only solution to store them was static folder actually but if You say so, I may need to find some other solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You are actually right and it should be in media files, not static -_-

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple html  tag to download static files

```
{% load static %} <!-- In top-->

<a href="{% static "mysite/resume.docx" %}" alt="My image">Click Here</a>
```

and keep the file(e.g. resume.docx) inside `myapp/static/mysite`

[image: static file path]