# Use static files in django/html for download gives 404

Tags: python, html, django, download, static

I am creating a web application in django when I wanted to create a static file download with html. I went into urls.py and modified it to have this at the end: `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`
Then I added this to index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<a href={% static "file.zip" %} download>Download File</a>
```

Then I added these lines to mysite.settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I then went into my base directory and added a directory called static.
I added the file file.zip into that directory, then went to the terminal and did a cd to the base directory. Finally, I run the command: python3 manage.py runserver
I then go to the server adress and click Download File.
At the bottom of the browser I then see:
File.zip
Failed- no file
So I look back to the terminal and I see:
"GET /static/file.zip HTTP/1.1" 404 1760
in orange. I see that this has a 404 at the end, so i look to stack overflow. I have spent days finding the answer, and so far i have tried:
[Django Static files 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404)
[Download static file displayed in the list Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842061/download-static-file-displayed-in-the-list-django)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
How do you make a working static file download with html and django?
Any working answer is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

hope this work!